# How to only get scheduled posts using php sdk and graph api?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I know you're meant to use promotable posts, and then i'm meant to use is_published=false. But where do i put this is_published=false? is it a limit? a field? the documentation says it's a modifier, but no where does it tell me how to add modifiers like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Simple!

/{id}/promotable_posts?is_published=true/false (whichever)

all modifiers are simply query parameters